# Error when trying to rename files with sed on mac os x

Tags: macos, sed, mv

I have a set of files that are sequentially numbered from 0001. What I'm trying to accomplish is to rename alter the name of the file, while keeping some pieces (such as nw, w) intact and start the numbering from 0000.

Original file names I have is as follows:

```
knifer dying nw  0001.png
knifer dying nw  0002.png
knifer dying nw  0003.png
knifer dying nw  0004.png
knifer dying nw  0005.png
knifer dying nw  0006.png
knifer dying nw  0007.png
knifer dying nw  0008.png
knifer dying nw  0009.png
knifer dying w  0001.png
knifer dying w  0002.png
knifer dying w  0003.png
knifer dying w  0004.png
knifer dying w  0005.png
knifer dying w  0006.png
knifer dying w  0007.png
knifer dying w  0008.png
knifer dying w  0009.png
```

What I want to accomplish is to make it look like this:

```
knifer_die_nw_0000.png <-- notice the _, the change of dying, keeping nw intact, and 0000
knifer_die_nw_0001.png
knifer_die_nw_0002.png
knifer_die_nw_0003.png
knifer_die_nw_0004.png
knifer_die_nw_0005.png
knifer_die_nw_0006.png
knifer_die_nw_0007.png
knifer_die_nw_0008.png
knifer_die_w_0000.png
knifer_die_w_0001.png
knifer_die_w_0002.png
knifer_die_w_0003.png
knifer_die_w_0004.png
knifer_die_w_0005.png
knifer_die_w_0006.png
knifer_die_w_0007.png
knifer_die_w_0008.png
```

I'm trying to write a script that does this by using sed. Below is the command I use to convert 0001 to 0000. For the other numbers I plan to include a change from 0002 to 0001, 0003 to 0002 and so forth. So, by turning this into a 10 line bash script I plan to achieve my target.

```
ls knifer*dying* | sed -E 's/knifer( |_)dying( |_)([a-z]{1,2})( ){1,2}0001(.*)/mv & knifer_die_\3_0000\5/'
mv knifer dying nw  0001.png knifer_die_nw_0000.png
knifer dying nw  0002.png
knifer dying nw  0003.png
knifer dying nw  0004.png
knifer dying nw  0005.png
knifer dying nw  0006.png
knifer dying nw  0007.png
knifer dying nw  0008.png
knifer dying nw  0009.png
mv knifer dying sw  0001.png knifer_die_sw_0000.png
knifer dying sw  0002.png
knifer dying sw  0003.png
knifer dying sw  0004.png
knifer dying sw  0005.png
knifer dying sw  0006.png
knifer dying sw  0007.png
knifer dying sw  0008.png
knifer dying sw  0009.png
```

I'm getting the output I need. Now, the problem comes if I try to execute it with **sh or bash** I get the following error :

```
 ls knifer*dying* | sed -E 's/knifer( |_)dying( |_)([a-z]{1,2})( ){1,2}0001(.*)/mv & knifer_die_\3_0000\5/' | sh
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
sh: line 2: knifer: command not found
sh: line 3: knifer: command not found
sh: line 4: knifer: command not found
sh: line 5: knifer: command not found
sh: line 6: knifer: command not found
sh: line 7: knifer: command not found
sh: line 8: knifer: command not found
sh: line 9: knifer: command not found
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
sh: line 11: knifer: command not found
sh: line 12: knifer: command not found
sh: line 13: knifer: command not found
sh: line 14: knifer: command not found
sh: line 15: knifer: command not found
sh: line 16: knifer: command not found
sh: line 17: knifer: command not found
sh: line 18: knifer: command not found
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4).

Comment: 1. What are the original file names and what do you want to transform them into? I'm not quite sure from your pattern. 2. Don't use `( |_)`, `[ _]` does that in shorter, clearer and without creating a group. 3. Your usage of mv seem weird, what are you moving where? 4. I'm sure the error comes from spaces in file names. You'd have to escape them. Using ls output isn't good there.

Comment: Added the original file names. I'm using mv to rename it in the same dir. Are you sure it's the spaces? Because the command seems to not work only during the bash call.

Comment: And the desired names? Your `mv` has many arguments ... Yes, sed can handle the spaces, but the `mv` call will think each word separated by a space is one file. So your call to mv thinks it's getting many files.

Comment: desired names are in the second block. I added a comment in bold there as well.

Comment: Well, that contains one mv command and many files. Why? If you wanted to move one file you don't need sed. Otherwise what's supposed to happen to the others?

Comment: `mv knifer dying nw  0001.png knifer_die_nw_0000.png` is a command that tries to move files named "knifer", "dying", "nw", and "0001.png" into a directory named "knifer_die_nw_0000.png". Since none of these exist, the command fails. All of the other lines start with `knifer`, which isn't a valid command at all. Please tell us [what you are actually trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since I'm pretty sure you're approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. I edited the question to elaborate what I'm trying to achieve. I understand that the problem is probably the space in the original file names. I'm still trying to think of a way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -name 'knifer*dying*' -print | while read file; do
    new_name=$(echo "$file" | awk ' { printf "knifer_die_%s_%04d.png", $3, $4-1 } ')
    mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

1. iterating of `ls` output isn't a good idea with spaces in the file names. `find` handles special file names better.
2. Since you need to store information (either the number or the new name), I recommend using a while read loop.
3. Awk separates the fields by spaces:

   - `$1`: 'knifer'
   - `$2`: 'dying'
   - `$3`: 'nw' or so
   - `$4`: 0001.png

   The `$4-1` tries to use parse it as a number and subtract one, so the '.png' is cut off.
   Then just combine the values in `printf`
4. Finally move the file. The double quote " are important!

Before moving please do a test run by replacing `mv` with `echo`

```
echo "$file" "$new_name"
```